# Dependabot is NOT creating pull requests for parent pom version

Tags: dependabot

Dependabot is NOT creating pull requests for parent pom version.

We are using maven 3.X as package manager. Our project uses a parent pom  version as below

```
 <parent>
     <groupId></groupId>
     <artifactId>xxxxx-base-java-webapp</artifactId>
     <version>2022.1.0</version>
     <type>pom</type>
</parent>
```

We have an several next versions of parent poms in nexus repository, but dependabot thinks an update is not needed. However it does work and create Pull requests  for regular dependencies specified with

```
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

```
dependabot.yml

    version: 2
    updates:
    - package-ecosystem: maven
      directory: "/xxxx"
      target-branch: "develop"
      open-pull-requests-limit: 10
```

```
Log file
2022-06-14T18:42:49.0954590Z Parsing dependencies information
2022-06-14T18:42:49.1031289Z Checking if xxxxx-base-java-webapp  needs updating
2022-06-14T18:42:49.1031933Z No update needed for xxxxx-base-java-webapp
```

Comment: [Comment on GitHub repo](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/5276#issuecomment-1409597575) claims this might be fixed in 2023